# Fetch user's Google Play balance with Google Play API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Google has an app called Google Opinion Rewards that shows the user's Google Play Balance on screen without having to initiate an in-app purchase.

[image]

I would like to do something similar: with given permission, fetch the user's balance and display it on screen.
So far I found nothing about that. The only way I found so far is to initiate an in-app purchase that would show a new window where the user would be able to pick a payment method and thus see their current credit balance.

Any direction will be very appreciated.

Only got to this documentation so far, which doesn't help much.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher?hl=en-us#subscriptions

I am not sure if that is a Google Play, Google Services or Google Pay issue.